# Is the elementary charge really a constant of nature? - Accuracy of QED

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, charge, discrete

There are a couple of natural constants; examples are Planck's constant or the Speed of light in vacuum. The elementary Charge is the coupling factor to all Kind of electromagnetic interactions; this is also a natural constant. Moreover, the fundamental theory of electromagnetic interaction - Quantum electrodynamics (QED) - is the most accurate field theory in physics.

But is the elementary Charge in General a fluctuating quantity such that it is governed by an additional Quantum field? I mean that one can replace the elementary Charge $e$ by a General elementary Charge $e \phi$ with a new Quantum field $\phi$ that is a scalar boson (Lorentz invariant) and governed by the Klein-Gordon equation. For $\phi \rightarrow 1$ ordinary Quantum electrodynamics is obtained. Since $e$ is not varying highly, the mass of the additional scalar boson must be assumed very large (therefore the Transfer of energy and momentum to this boson is very little). Also self-interactions are contained in the theory; but for $\phi \rightarrow 1$ These self-interactions can be neglected.

Is such an Extension of QED possible? (Maybe one can study Quantum-electrodynamic fluctuations more precisely with this Extension.) Are above assumptions plausible?

Comment: Are you aware of [running couplings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_constant#Running_coupling)? The charge is really not constant when you crank up the energy level already

Comment: I know that there are existing running couplings. With the additional scalar field it might be possible to model the dependence of coupling constant on the energy scale. I think,it is not known what is the relation between $e$ and $\mu$.

Comment: Oh, it is perfectly known, that's what the beta functions/Callen-Symanzik equations are for. How else would we know of asymptotic freedom/landau poles/RG fixed points?

Comment: Also, note that adding a scalar field to terms containing the electric charge would make the corresponding terms non-renormalizable, since their mass dimension would be increased, so this is not a good idea.